# Mercurial leaving locks behind often

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Where I work we are using Mercurial for a repository (on a server) with about 12 people working accessing it to push/pull at any given time. I am not particularly familiar with Mercurial or any VCS, but have been asked to look into an issue we are having recently.

As the team size has grown we have started to get locks left around multiple times a day, impeding people from working. The lock sometimes is the persons own computer or is held by our deployment service TeamCity server.

Looking around the furthest solutions seem to go are "Delete the locks", but this is becoming unfeasible to do multiple times a day and is a sign of issues. Would this be down to our team size or something else? Sorry, I know this question is quite vague on the details, but if you need further information let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated even pointing me in the right direction.

Our workflow generally consists of - individual branches for features/bug fixes which we then merge into a branch for release/testing which will then finally get merged into our default branch for people to branch work from.

We are all using Mercurial-4.3.1 and we are using windows share to clone.

Comment: What is your Mercurial version? Are you using a Windows share to access the repository?

Comment: It is on a server and we are individually cloning it to use locally via HG Mercurial - sorry for the late response.

Comment: You clone via HTTP or SSH?

Comment: I believe it is HTTP

Comment: What is the verison of Mercurial running on the server? And the OS version?

Comment: We are all using Mercurial-4.3.1 and my earlier comment was incorrect; we are using windows share to clone.

Comment: I can only say, we've had similar issues (though not as frequent).

Answer (score 2):

Windows shares **don't** work well with Mercurial.

The best option to avoid this issues, should be to use `hg serve`, or to use [another hosting method](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PublishingRepositories).

Comment: The issue seems to have lessened if not stopped entirely since 1 of 2 things has happened. We identified incorrect permissions, resvolved that, but also a member of the team left. I will look into what you have mentioned here, thanks for taking a look at this question.

Comment: Anecdotally I agree that hg serve seems to avoid this problem.